# Type Hinting DynamoDb Query Output

Tags: typescript, amazon-dynamodb

How can I define the shape of my Query Items Result in the following Typescript code

```
const request: DynamoDB.DocumentClient.QueryInput = {
    TableName: UnsubscriptionTokensRepository.TABLE_NAME,
    IndexName: 'TokenIndex',
    KeyConditionExpression: 'unsubscriptionToken = :unsubscriptionToken',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':unsubscriptionToken': token
    }
};
const result = await this._documentClient.query(request).promise();
return result.Items[0].id;
```

So my Dynamodb results contains an object having different keys. For example in the last line I am using `id` field which Typescript has no idea.

Answer (score 0):

lets say the Table UnsubscriptionTokensRepository.
Table name is defined by a object :Token.
result  can be defined as a Object like this:

```
class QueryResponseTokens {
  Items:Array<Token>
}
```